# Progress to next block after fixed duration in Qualtrics

Tags: qualtrics

I have a Qualtrics survey where respondents do one of 4 conditions. In one condition, they are required to answer questions for 3 minutes.

These questions have to be in a random order and presented on one page each, and there has to be a maximum number of questions answered of 90 (I have timers before questions enabling submit after 2 seconds).

So the questions are all in one block, but I cannot figure out how to progress to the next block (skipping the remaining questions) if the respondent does not answer all questions in 3 minutes.

I've got no background in coding so although I've tried some JavaScript that I've scraped from googling, I don't know how to make it work, so please ask if I haven't been clear and provide idiot-proof answers :)

I created an Embedded variable called TimeLeft and set that to 180 and tried inserting the code below into all questions in the block.

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
    var timeleft = parseInt("${e://Field/TimeLeft})");

        var timer = setInterval(function(){
            if(timeleft <= 0){
                clearInterval(timer);
                $('NextButton').click();
            }
            timeleft--;
        },1000);

    $('NextButton').onclick = function (event) {
    Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData('TimeLeft', timeleft);
    }

});
```

When I test it (with 10 seconds instead of 3 minutes), it seems to advance each individual question after 10 seconds but does not skip the block. If I answer a question, it advances the next question by 10 minus the amount of time I took to answer. e.g. If I answer the first question in 2 seconds, all next questions will auto advance after 8 seconds.
In this case I would want it to take 10 seconds in total, regardless of how long I've taken to respond. e.g. If I take 2 seconds to answer the first question, even if I do not answer the next question it should advance to the next block after 8 seconds.

I'm not sure if I am putting the JS in the right places or if it is incomplete. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Do you have display logic set on the questions in the block to the effect of "show this question if timeleft > 0"?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Kevin. Unfortunately because of timing I've had to change my setup (each question now appears for 4 seconds only, regardless of whether the subject can answer it). Anyway I appreciate you taking the time to answer.